# Rails Delete a record from nested-resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Charge` model that is a subset of a `Quotes` model.

```
resources :quotes do
  resources :charges
end
```

I want to delete a `charge` while on an edit page of a quote.

quotes/_form.html.haml

```
- @quote.charges.each do |charge|
  %tr
    %td
      = link_to 'x', charge, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this charge?', :method => :delete
```

When I load the page I get undefined method `charge_path' for #<#:0x0000012f8a2ea8>. I've also tried:

```
= link_to 'x', quote_charge_path(charge), :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this charge?', :method => :delete
```

And that appears to work, but it seems to have the quote id and the charge id in the wrong order. For example, the URL that generates is `<a href="/quotes/11/charges/13" ...` It should actually be `/quotes/13/charges/11`. Anyone know how to do this correctly? Thanks.

### Update

Interestingly, what ended up working was `= link_to '×', [@quote, charge], :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this charge?', :method => :delete, :class => "close"`. When I was specifying the path `quote_charge_path([@quote, charge])` it was creating the wrong url. Not sure why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested route helpers you need to pass in both the parent and the child object. Try

```
quote_charge_path([@quote, charge])
```

Comment: Hey @carlosramireziii, for some reason the url that's being generated from this is `<a href="/quotes/13/11/charges/13" ...`. Any idea why there would be that initial `13` after quotes?